# type mismatch in for cycle

Tags: excel, vba

my code get an error in the line

`If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then`

I don't know why, from my little experience there's nothing wrong but i keep getting this Type mismatch (Error 13), can someone help me? here's my full code

```
Sub tests()
'Option Explicit

'Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim orig As String
Dim v As Variant
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim exApp As Excel.Application
Dim exwb As Excel.Workbook


'Application.EnableEvents = True
'On Error GoTo Exitsub

Set wbBook = Workbooks("SHELF LIFE.xlsm")
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Sheets("Shelf Life Data")

Set exApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Workbooks.Open ("link.xlsm")
Set exwb = Workbooks("file name.xlsm")
    
With exwb
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row
    v = .Sheets("SINCE 170522").Range(Cells(4, 12), Cells(lastrow, 12)).Value
    .Close
End With

With wsSheet
    .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)).Value = v
    .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 2)).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, _
        Header:=xlYes
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastrow To 2 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = .Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
        Next i
End With

Exitsub:

End Sub
```

Comment: When you get the error, look at the values yourself in the watch window. Is one a string and the other a number? The string might LOOK like a number but that does not mean it IS a number.

Comment: You'll get that error if one of the cell values being compared is an error.

Comment: You got `lastrow` from a range starting on row#**4**, so you need to adjust that if you want to place the array starting at row#**2**, or your last 2 values will be `#N/A` (and hence your error about type mismatch)  FYI no need to create a separate Excel application instance to open the other file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got `lastrow` from a range starting on row#**4**, so you need to adjust that if you want to place the array starting at row#**2**, or your last 2 values will be `#N/A` because the range you're placing the array onto is larger than the array.

Those `#N/A` values account for the "type mismatch" error when you start to loop over the values.

You can do this instead:
`.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(v, 1), 1).Value = v`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refer to the sheet in the `With` statement, you have to start `Cells` with a dot.

```
lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row

------------------------------------------------

lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

As in the code they refer to the "link.xlsm" sheet, because it is the ActiveSheet.